# How to get the last item in foreach loop writing to CSV?

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-web-api, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I'm having trouble getting the last item in the loop Writing to CSV, I don't want the last item in CSV to have a `,` at the end.

**This is the public string to write my controller to CSV**

```
    public string WriteTsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
        {
            output.Append(prop.DisplayName); // header
            output.Append(", \t");
        }
        output.AppendLine();
        foreach (T item in data) 
        {
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                output.Append(prop.Converter.ConvertToString(
                     prop.GetValue(item)));
                output.Append(", \t");
            }
            output.AppendLine();
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }
```

I've been stuck on this for a while now hoping anyone could help.

Comment: Remove the last 3 characters before appending the line

Comment: how to do that? can you show me the code using my controller @dbmitch?

Comment: If you want to get the last item try using a `for` instead of `foreach` loop. Then you can check the current `for` index against the `props` count and when it's the last item you can bypass appending ', \t'.

Comment: `", \t"` seems a peculiar field separate for CSV - it should just be `","`. I would use `String.Join` instead of a loop: `String.Join(",", props.Select(prop => prop.Converter.ConvertToString(prop.GetValue(item))))`

Comment: can you show me the code for that inside my controller @NetMage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code, the simplest approach would be to remove the last 3 characters (final `", \t"`) before each call to `AppendLine()` using the fact that  the [StringBuilder.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.length?view=net-6.0) property is writeable.

So, instead of just

```
output.AppendLine();
```

do

```
output.Length -=3;
output.AppendLine();
```

From the same documentation it says,

> If the specified length is less than the current length, the current **StringBuilder** object is truncated to the specified length.

You will, of course, need to do some error checking if you think there could be a string of less than length 3. You may also want to watch out for properties whose string value actually end in `, \t`...

Comment: The last statement isn't relevant - unless you are suggesting concern that the CSV needs quotes to handle commas in values properly, in which it doesn't matter where in the value the separator is found.

Comment: thanks Kit, this was a really simple answer without rebuilding my controller, really help me alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Join` to combine an `IEnumerable<T>` with a separator and then use `AppendLine` to add to the `output`. I used `Cast<T>()` to convert the `IEnumerable` implementation from the legacy `PropertyDescriptorCollection` to a modern `IEnumerable<T>`. (Unfortunately, a lot of C# hasn't been updated to properly support `IEnumerable<T>`.)

```
public string WriteTsv<T>(IEnumerable<T> data) {
    var output = new StringBuilder();
    var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T)).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>();
    // header
    output.AppendLine(String.Join(",", props.Select(prop => prop.DisplayName)));
    // data
    foreach (T item in data)
        output.AppendLine(String.Join(",", props.Select(prop => prop.Converter.ConvertToString(prop.GetValue(item)))));
    return output.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It works but you rebuild my controller, but thanks for this code NetMage